# How to synchronize a TargetDataLine and SourceDataLine in Java (Synchronize audio recording and playback)

Tags: java, audio, synchronization, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I am trying to create a Java application that is able to play an audio playback,  record the user voice and tell if the user sing in tune and at the right time.

For the moment, I just focus on the record and play audio (tune recognition is out of scope).

For this purpose, I used TargetDataLine and SourceDataLine from the Java audio API. At first, I start the audio record and then I launch the audio playback. Since I want to ensure that the user sing at the right time, I need to keep a synchronization between the audio recorded and the audio played.

For example, if the audio playback starts 1 second after the audio recording, I know that I will ignore the first second of data in the record buffer.

I use the following code for my tests (the code is far from being perfect but it's just for testing purpose).

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class AudioSynchro {

private TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
private SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
private AudioInputStream ais;
private AudioFormat recordAudioFormat;
private AudioFormat playAudioFormat;

public AudioSynchro(String sourceFile) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(sourceFile));

    recordAudioFormat = new AudioFormat(44100f, 16, 1, true, false);
    playAudioFormat = ais.getFormat();
}

//Enumerate the mixers
public void enumerate() {
    try {
        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo =
                AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        System.out.println("Available mixers:");
        for(int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length;
            cnt++){
            System.out.println(mixerInfo[cnt].
                    getName());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Init datalines
public void initDataLines() throws LineUnavailableException {
    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo =
            AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    DataLine.Info targetDataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, recordAudioFormat);

    Mixer targetMixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[5]);

    targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine)targetMixer.getLine(targetDataLineInfo);

    DataLine.Info sourceDataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, playAudioFormat);

    Mixer sourceMixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[3]);

    sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine)sourceMixer.getLine(sourceDataLineInfo);
}

public void startRecord() throws LineUnavailableException {
    AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine);

    targetDataLine.open(recordAudioFormat);

    byte currentByteBuffer[] = new byte[512];

    Runnable readAudioStream = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            try {
                targetDataLine.start();
                while ((count = stream.read(currentByteBuffer)) != -1) {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(readAudioStream);
    thread.start();
}

public void startPlay() throws LineUnavailableException {
    sourceDataLine.open(playAudioFormat);
    sourceDataLine.start();

    Runnable playAudio = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int nBytesRead = 0;
                byte[] abData = new byte[8192];
                while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                    nBytesRead = ais.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                    if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                        int nBytesWritten = sourceDataLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                    }
                }

                sourceDataLine.drain();
                sourceDataLine.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(playAudio);
    thread.start();
}

public void printStats() {
    Runnable stats = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                long targetDataLinePosition = targetDataLine.getMicrosecondPosition();
                long sourceDataLinePosition = sourceDataLine.getMicrosecondPosition();
                long delay = targetDataLinePosition - sourceDataLinePosition;
                System.out.println(targetDataLinePosition+"\t"+sourceDataLinePosition+"\t"+delay);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(stats);
    thread.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        AudioSynchro audio = new AudioSynchro("C:\\dev\\intellij-ws\\guitar-challenge\\src\\main\\resources\\com\\ouestdev\\guitarchallenge\\al_adagi.mid");
        audio.enumerate();
        audio.initDataLines();
        audio.startRecord();
        audio.startPlay();
        audio.printStats();
    } catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The code initialize the 2 datalines, starts the audio recording, starts the audio playback and displays statistics. The enumerate() method is used to display the mixers available on the system. You have to change the mixers used in the initDataLines() method depending on your system to do your own tests.
The printStats method() starts a thread that ask the position in microsecond of the 2 datalines. This is the data that I try to use to keep a track of the synchronization. What I observe is that the 2 datalines don't stay synchronized all the time. Here is a short extract of my output console :

130000  0   130000

150000  748 149252

170000  20748   149252

190000  40748   149252

210000  60748   149252

230000  80748   149252

250000  100748  149252

270000  120748  149252

290000  140748  149252

310000  160748  149252

330000  180748  149252

350000  190748  159252

370000  210748  159252

390000  240748  149252

410000  260748  149252

430000  280748  149252

450000  300748  149252

470000  310748  159252

490000  340748  149252

510000  350748  159252

530000  370748  159252

As we can see, the delay may vary from 10 milliseconds regularly so I can't tell with precision which position in recording buffer match with the beginning of the playback buffer. Especially, in the previous example,  I Don't know if I should start at the position 149252 or 159252.
When it comes to audio processing, 10 milliseconds is important and I would like something more accurate (1 or 2 milliseconds is acceptable). 
Moreover, it sounds really weird that when there is a difference between 2 measures, it's still a gap of 10 milliseconds.

I then tried to push my tests further but I don't get better results :
- Tried with bigger or smaller buffers
- Tried a buffer twice bigger for the playback. Since the audio file is in stereo more bytes are consumed (2 bytes/frame for recording and 4/bytes/frame for playing)
- Tried to record and play on the same audio device

In my opinion, there two strategy to synchronize the 2 buffers :
- What I try to do. Determine with precision the position in the recording buffer where the playback start.
- Synchronize the start of the recording and the playback.

In both of these strategies, I need to guaranty that the synchronization is maintained.

Has any of you ever experienced this type of problem ?

At the moment, I use Java 12 and JavaFx for my application but I am ready to use another framework. I have not tried but it may be possible to get better results and more control with the frameworks lwjgl (https://www.lwjgl.org/ is based on OpenAl) or beads (http: // www.beadsproject.net/). If anyone of you knows his frameworks and can give me a return, I'm interested.

Finally, the last acceptable solution is to change the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not done much with `TargetDataLines` yet, but I think I can offer a useful observation and suggestion.

First, the test you have written is probably measuring variance in the multi-threading algorithm, not slippage in the timing of the files. The way the JVM bounces back and forth between processing threads can be quite unpredictable. There is a [good article on real time, low-latency coding in Java](https://diuf.unifr.ch/main/pai/sites/diuf.unifr.ch.main.pai/files/publications/2007_Juillerat_Mueller_Schubiger-Banz_Real_Time.pdf) that you might read for background information.

Secondly, the way that Java uses blocking queues with audio IO provides a lot of stability. If it didn't, we'd hear all sorts of audio artifacts during playback or on our recordings.

Here is an idea to try: create a single `runnable` that has a `while` loop that processes an identical number of frames from both the `TargetDataLine` and the `SourceDataLine` in the same iteration. This `runnable` can be loosely coupled (use booleans to turn on/off the lines).

The main benefit is that you know that every loop iteration is producing coordinated data.

---

EDIT: Here are a couple examples of what I've done with frame counting: 
(1) I have an audio loop that counts frames as it processes. All timings are determined strictly by the number of frames processed. I never bother with taking readings from the position of the SDL. I've written a metronome, and it initiates a synthesized click every N frames (where N is based on tempo). At the Nth frame, the data for the synthesized click is mixed into the audio data that is being sent out of the SDL. The accuracy in timing that I have obtained by this method is outstanding.

Another application, on the Nth frame, I initiated a visual/graphical event. The graphics loop is usually set to 60fps and the audio to 44100 fps. The initiation is handled via loose coupling: a boolean for the event is flipped by the audio thread (nothing more than that, cluttering the audio thread with extraneous activity is hazardous, can lead to stuttering and dropouts). The graphics processing loop (aka "game loop") picks up the boolean change and handles it in its own time (60 fps). I've had some nice visual + aural synchronization occur this way, including having objects whose brightness tracks with the volume of the sound being played. This is similar to the digital VU meters that many have written using Java.

Depending on the level of accuracy you are hoping for, I think frame counting can be sufficient. I don't know of any other way, with Java, that provides as much accuracy.

Comment: Hi Phil, Thanks for your answer. I'll take a look at the article and I'll try your idea. I'll keep you informed of the result.

Comment: Cool. Also, if there is a need to put in an offset, so that SDL frame #(N) is compared to TDL frame #(N - X), the shared while loop would help keep things aligned in a predictable way. For example, a circular queue buffer could be managed in the while loop for the passing data. Looking forward to hearing how this goes! I want to get to pitch-testing as well at some point.

Comment: I don't know if you get pinged when I make edits to my answer. This comment is to let you know that I've added a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Phil, I will try to work with frames

Answer (score 0):

I made new tests with the following code (Phil, tell me if that's what you had in mind).

```
public void startAll() throws LineUnavailableException, IOException {
    AudioInputStream stream = new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine);

    targetDataLine.open(recordAudioFormat);

    byte reccordByteBuffer[] = new byte[512];
    byte playByteBuffer[] = new byte[1024];


    sourceDataLine.open(playAudioFormat);
    targetDataLine.start();
    sourceDataLine.start();

    Runnable audio = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int reccordCount = 0;
            int totalReccordCount = 0;
            int playCount = 0;
            int totalPlayCount = 0;
            int playWriteCount = 0;
            int totalWritePlayCount = 0;
            try {
                while (playCount != -1) {
                    reccordCount = stream.read(reccordByteBuffer);
                    totalReccordCount += reccordCount;
                    long targetDataLinePosition = targetDataLine.getLongFramePosition();
                    playCount = ais.read(playByteBuffer, 0, playByteBuffer.length);
                    playWriteCount = sourceDataLine.write(playByteBuffer, 0, playCount);
                    totalPlayCount += playCount;
                    totalWritePlayCount += playWriteCount;
                    long sourceDataLinePosition = sourceDataLine.getLongFramePosition();


                    long delay = targetDataLinePosition - sourceDataLinePosition;
                    System.out.println(targetDataLinePosition + "\t" + sourceDataLinePosition + "\t" + delay + "\t" + totalReccordCount + "\t" + totalPlayCount + "\t" + totalWritePlayCount + "\t" + System.nanoTime());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(audio);
    thread.start();

}
```

And here are the results (I only put pieces because the stack is very long).

1439300 <-- Offset in ns between the start of the TargetDataLine and the SourceDataLine.

119297  0   119297  512 1024    1024    565993368423500

179297  0   179297  1024    2048    2048    565993388887000

189297  0   189297  1536    3072    3072    565993390006000

189297  0   189297  2048    4096    4096    565993390998900

189297  0   189297  2560    5120    5120    565993391737300

189297  0   189297  3072    6144    6144    565993392430700

189297  0   189297  3584    7168    7168    565993392608000

189297  0   189297  4096    8192    8192    565993393295200

189297  0   189297  4608    9216    9216    565993393971900

189297  0   189297  5120    10240   10240   565993394690200

189297  0   189297  5632    11264   11264   565993395476900

189297  0   189297  6144    12288   12288   565993396160600

189297  0   189297  6656    13312   13312   565993396864500

189297  0   189297  7168    14336   14336   565993397032000

189297  0   189297  7680    15360   15360   565993397736000

189297  0   189297  8192    16384   16384   565993398467800

199297  0   199297  8704    17408   17408   565993399156300

---

199297  0   199297  15360   30720   30720   565993406362500

199297  0   199297  15872   31744   31744   565993407001900

199297  0   199297  16384   32768   32768   565993407585200

329297  115804  213493  16896   33792   33792   565993532785500 <-- The playback starts here

329297  115804  213493  17408   34816   34816   565993533320600

329297  115804  213493  17920   35840   35840   565993533486300

---

329297  115804  213493  22016   44032   44032   565993536512600

329297  115804  213493  22528   45056   45056   565993536941700

329297  125804  203493  23040   46080   46080   565993537363100 <-- The SourceDataLine increments by 10 ms but not the TargetDataLine

329297  125804  203493  23552   47104   47104   565993537746900

329297  125804  203493  24064   48128   48128   565993538158600

339297  125804  213493  24576   49152   49152   565993538306400 <-- The TargetDataLine increments by 10 ms but not the SourceDataLine. The situation is recovering.

339297  125804  213493  25088   50176   50176   565993538762200

---

469297  255804  213493  39424   78848   78848   565993674194900

469297  255804  213493  39936   79872   79872   565993674513700

469297  255804  213493  40448   80896   80896   565993674872000

469297  255804  213493  40960   81920   81920   565993675177000

599297  385804  213493  41472   82944   82944   565993800684100 <-- The TargetDataLine and SourceDataLine increment by 10 ms. There is no lag.

599297  385804  213493  41984   83968   83968   565993800871800

599297  385804  213493  42496   84992   84992   565993801189300

599297  385804  213493  43008   86016   86016   565993801486800

599297  385804  213493  43520   87040   87040   565993801814500

My observations are as follows:

- Even if the 2 datalines are started at the same time, there is a significant gap between them. The measurement made with System.out.println (System.nanoTime() - targetStart); indicates an offset of 1.4393 ms while the delay variable is between 213.493 ms and 203.493 ms. So we can not hold the solution to start both datalines at the same time to get a perfect synchronization.
- SourceDataLine received 33792 bytes before starting to play
- We can see that the precision of the getMicrosecondPosition() method is not very good (getLongFramePosition() is not better and getMicrosecondPosition() is based on it for its calculation). Indeed, for the targetDataline (record), we see that the value 189297 is displayed 14 times. The time spent between the 14 displays estimated by the System.nanoTime() method is 8.4618 ms! This seems to confirm that it is not possible to obtain a precision less than 10 ms with this method.
- In my case, the Java implementations used are DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL and DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL (there are other implementations especially depending on the OS). The low level method that is called is static native long nGetBytePosition(long id, boolean isSource, long javaPos). This method is native so it calls for an implementation in another language (which must certainly appeal to the driver). The lack of precision comes from this method and not directly from the Java code.
- It can be seen that the offset occurs when one of the datalines takes another 10 ms and the other remains at the old value. The offset is resorbed when the other also takes 10 ms extra. this phenomenon was much less obvious with the printStats() method because we used Thread.sleep(20).
- The fact of being passed on a single thread does not change much. So I think the Java Audio API is just not accurate enough for what I'm trying to accomplish.
- The document Phil refers to in his commentary indicates that the results were inconclusive with the Java Sound API and that they were passed through RtAudio and a mapping with Java.

Comment: Hi - I didn't know you had replied, was just checking back since I hadn't heard anything. It is best to leave a comment on the thread of my reply so that I get a notification. I may get a ding if you reply here. IDK. 
I see that you are reading from the audio input (TDL) 512 bytes and writing the to SDL 1024 bytes. Good. I'm guessing something like input is mono and output is stereo, hence the doubling? I am claiming that as long as the 3rd and 4th columns remain 1:2, some back and forth in the readings from getXXXXPosition methods is to be expected but not particularly important.

Comment: The key (if I understand your goal) is to know what frame on the input line corresponds to the frame location of the event you want to match on the SDL. Let's say there is a click for every beat on the SDL, and you know this occurs 2 x's a second (120 BPM) (and can see it in the data via RMS analysis). These should occur every 44100/2 frames. Determine your tolerance for a hit "on the beat" and analyze the incoming and see if the singer has placed their sound within +/- tolerance in terms of frame position on the incoming line. This should be quite accurate. Rely on your frame count.